# LinkedIn Api issue

Tags: linkedin-api

Im trying to use linkedin API’s
In specific simpleJobPosting ( which is like i read in the documentation its an api that is used to create a post on linkedIn profile )
I followed all the steps ,, created an app on the linkedIn portal and got ClientId and ClientSecret ,, I’ve generated an access token and verified the organization that I selected,, also i selected the suitable scope before generating an access token (w_member_social)
when I tested it on PostMan I still got an error which is said
U don’t have enough permission to access Post/simpleJobPosting with status 403 and error code 100
I checked the documentation for the error status and said ensure that the header x-restli-method with value batch_create is present and i already included it in the headers and all the other steps
any suggestions ??

[step1-As shown here i created an app and got clientId,ClientSecret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpX0f.png)
[step2-i selected the suitable scope(permission)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwRAM.png)
[step3-i've generated an access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9rfJ.png)
[step4-verified the company that i've selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7tc2.png) 
[step5-postman request details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXRN6.png)

Comment: You forgot to include the code you are using, and the error messages you are facing

Comment: i even did not use any code yet ,, i just try it through postman

Comment: If you haven't written any code, this question is off-topic here